# How can I improve the performance of the JbossFuse (v6.3) DSL route code?

Tags: java-8, ibm-mq, jbossfuse

***APPLICATION INFO:***

Code below: reads from IBM MQ queue and then posts the message to a REST service

*(**note**: reading from the MQ queue is fast and **not** an issue - rather, it is the **post** operation performance I am having trouble improving)...*

***PROBLEM:***

Unable to output/post more than 44-47 messages per second...

***QUESTION:***

How can I improve the performance of the JbossFuse (v6.3) DSL route code below?...   *(What techniques are available that would make it faster?)*

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.cdi.ContextName;

@ContextName("rest-dsl")
public class Netty4HttpSlowRoutes extends RouteBuilder {

    public Netty4HttpSlowRoutes() {
    }

    private final org.apache.camel.Processor proc1 = new Processor1();    

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

    org.apache.log4j.MDC.put("app.name", "netty4HttpSlow");

    System.getProperties().list(System.out);
    errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler().maximumRedeliveries(3).log("***FAILED_MESSAGE***"));   

    from("wmq:queue:mylocalqueue")
        .log("inMessage=" + (null==body()?"":body().toString()))
        .to("seda:node1?concurrentConsumers=20");

    from("seda:node1")
        .streamCaching()
        .threads(20)
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.POST))
        .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
        .toD("netty4-http:http://localhost:7001/MyService/myServiceThing?textline\\=true");      
    }           
}
```

Comment: Is your contention with the reading the messages from MQ or the posting them to the REST service?

Comment: posting to the rest service.   the mq read is fast.

Comment: I'm a MQ Admin so do not have any advise for you on the REST service end of things.

Comment: I understand!  Thx, JoshMc!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of thoughts. First things first: did you measure the slowness? How much time do you spend in Camel VS how much time you spend sending the HTTP request?
If the REST service is slow there's nothing you can do in Camel. Depending on what the service does, you could try reducing the number of threads.

Try to disable streamCaching since it looks like you're not using it.

Then use a `to` instead of `toD` to invoke the service, I see that the URL is always the same. In the [docs of ToD](http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html) I read

> By default the Simple language is used to compute the endpoint.

There may be a little overhead while parsing the URI string each time you invoke the route.

Comment: Hi Alessandro - I'm new to JBoss Fuse, camel blueprint.   -I posted a rough model of the actual code whereby system.properties is used to obtain the URL value - hence the "ToD".    Original code also has a "process()" method which I thought the "streamCaching" would help(?).  The queue drains very fast.   The "bottleneck" appears to be focused upon the REST post request(?).   Wondered whether there might be a way to "spray" the REST requests?  Question: Is camel-netty4-http the right choice for performance?  (again, I'm using camel blueprint). thx!